# ListView количество выбранных элементов

Tags: android, android-studio, listview

Для того, чтобы получить индексы выбранных элементов ListView, использую следующий метод:

`SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray = myListView.getCheckedItemPositions();`

А далее получаю количество элементов путем обращения к методу

```
sparseBooleanArray.size()
```

Эти действия находятся в обработчике нажатия на пункт меню.

Все работает корректно до тех пор, пока не случается следующая ситуация: в ListView нет элементов, но была нажата кнопка, на которую реагирует обработчик, упомянутый выше. Таким образом, в `sparseBooleanArray` хранятся данные, которые были выбраны в последний раз, соответственно, sparseBooleanArray.size() возвращает не 0.

В чем причина?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел выход: дополнительно проверяю `myListView.getCount()`, возвращающий количество элементов в ListView.

Answer (score 3):

Этот список вообще хранит состояние всех элементов которые менялись за всё время работы `ListView`. То есть не только выбранных, но и отменённых.
А получить количество реально отмеченных можно так:

```
         int count = myListView.getCheckedItemCount();
```

Comment: данный метод возвращает количество элементов, отмеченных за все время

Comment: Всё правильно - количество всех помеченных на текущий момент. Вам нужно что-то другое?

Comment: дело в том, что когда я отмечаю элементы, то далее добавляю их в БД, а при следующем вызове фрагмента с ListView добавленные элементы уже не отображаются в списке. таким образом, когда я начинаю снова отмечать элементы, данный метод возвращает количество элементов, отмеченных ранее + количество элементов, отмеченных на данный момент

Comment: После отправки в базу можно вызвать у списка `clearChoices()` - это сбросит и счётчик и список, который возвращает `getCheckedItemPositions()`